# How to correct this error “django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing:”

Tags: django

How to correct this error:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to
>   create the django_migrations table ((1064, "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1"))

I can use it on another computer, and this is caused by creating a database using the `python manage.py migrate` statement.

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` beforehand?

Comment: It's happening because of Django and MySql version mismatching.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, Mysql version does not match. Does not support version 5.5, I can change to version 5.6.